# Windows Server 2012 - CPU utilization

Tags: windows, central-processing-unit, multi-core

I have Windows Server 2012 machine which has 32 cores. In Task Manager, it shows 32 cores and 64 logical processors, because of hyperthreading.

My CPU utilization is in the screenshot below:

[image]

Can anyone give me an overview of what this screenshot shows? Why are half of the logical processors idle while the other half are at 100% utilization? How can I take advantage of all of the logical processors with my application?

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess (which is all that this is), your application is not capable of taking advantage of more than two physical CPU. So, you're maxing out two physical CPU and the other two are relatively idle.

The screencap shows that you have 4 sockets (4 physical processors) with 32 cores, which means that each socket has 8 physical cores and 16 logical cores.